# SVG mask not loading initially in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, mask

Working on a project which is using a SVG mask on the homepage hero component but for some reason the text in the mask only shows when I resize the window. It's not showing on the initial page load. This is happening only in Chrome (latest version).

You can view the example on the STAGING environment here: https://staging.erwconstructions.com.au/

HTML Markup is:

```
<section data-component="mask-hero" class="in-view mask-hero">
  <picture>
    <img src="https://staging.erwconstructions.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/home-hero.jpg" alt="Home">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100% 100%">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" />
        </linearGradient>
        <mask id="mask">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
          <text x="0" y="50%">
            <tspan x="5vw" dy="-.1em">Building</tspan>
            <tspan x="5vw" dy="1em">Redefined</tspan>
          </text>
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" fill-opacity="0.9" mask="url(#mask)" />
    </svg>
  </picture>
</section>
```

The CSS is:

```
[data-component="mask-hero"] {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  & picture {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    & img {
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
      position: fixed;
      will-change: transform;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    & svg {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
    }
    & text {
      font-family: var(--defaultFont);
      font-weight: var(--bold);
      font-size: 3em;
      @media (--app-breakpoint-2) {
        font-size: 6em;
      }
      @media (--app-breakpoint-4) {
        font-size: 8em;
      }
      @media (--app-breakpoint-5) {
        font-size: 14em;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason there is also a console error regarding the viewBox, even though the correct attributes are set on the SVG:

`Error: <svg> attribute viewBox: Expected number, "0 0 100% 100%".`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dayne

Answer (score 0):

By the given error, I'd guess to problem is with the `viewBox`. It should be given an absolute number in px, not percent. Like `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">`

Comment: Thanks for responding but when I change the viewBox to: 0 0 100 100 it looks like this:

https://snipboard.io/xwm5Ej.jpg

Doesn't span the entire viewport width and height and still doesn't show the text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using javascript to make it work ?
This code below adds background color to white on rect inside svg code to show the text when the page has loaded.

`var svgRect = document.querySelector('svg rect');document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ setTimeout(function() { svgRect.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; }, 500); });`